# Need to override the default time out of Axios post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, timeout, settimeout

When I'm making a post request with axios from client-side(React JS) to the server(spring), the response time of server is more than 2 minutes. So client is not waiting to receive the response when it takes more tan 2 minutes. So I tried to override the default timeout with the below code snippet. But it is not working.Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

```
const httpClient = Axios.create();
httpClient.defaults.timeout = 240000;

return httpClient.post(url, data).then(
 res => res
).catch(err => err);
```

Comment: I'd suggest instead splitting that into two stages, see e.g. https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs/

Answer (score 7):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-order-of-precedence) (This is another topic but shows an example for timeout).

There is two ways of setting the `timeout`.

```
// Create an instance using the config defaults provided by the library
// At this point the timeout config value is `0` as is the default for the library
const instance = axios.create();

// Override timeout default for the library
// Now all requests using this instance will wait 2.5 seconds before timing out
instance.defaults.timeout = 2500;

// Override timeout for this request as it's known to take a long time
instance.get('/longRequest', {
  timeout: 5000
});
```

You can override the default with `instance.defaults.timeout` or pass it as an option to your call.

You can also see another [example in the docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance).

If it isn't working, probably you have a outdated version of axios or you are missing something.

Answer (score 1):

When time of creation of axios instance which will be applied to all api calls

```
const httpClient = Axios.create({ timeout: 2 * 60 * 1000 });
```

You can pass `timeout` parameter in api call

```
httpClient.post(url, data, { timeout: 2 * 60 * 1000 })
```

Comment: This approach is working fine for the timeout less than 2 minutes. When I try with timeout of 3 minutes, it is throwing error as "Failed to load response data".

Comment: And also we are not able to capture the response with the timeout, getting response as "Failed to load response data"

Comment: When a get a timeout error, response will be empty, nothing,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this if you are on `nodejs17.3+` is as follows.

```js
await axios({
             method: 'post',
             url: url,
             headers: headers,
             data: payload,
             signal: AbortSignal.timeout(2 * 60 * 1000), // this will handle connection timeout. After waiting for 2 minutes an exception will be thrown
             timeout: 2 * 60 * 1000 // This one handles ONLY response timeout
            })
```

Note that you have to handle connection timeout and response timeout separately.

Reference: [Official documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation)